# Linked List error - Why are head and tail references pointing to the same address?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

While in the process of implementing a Linked List in C++, I ran into an issue with my function for inserting a new element at the tail end of the list.

```
struct LinkedNode
{
    int data;
    LinkedNode* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    LinkedNode* head;
    LinkedNode* tail;
    int size;
public:
    LinkedList();
    void insert_back(int element);
    int at(int index);
    int length();
};
```

Originally, my insert_back function was as follows:

```
void LinkedList::insert_back(int element)
{
    LinkedNode node = {element, 0};
    if(size == 0)
    {
        head = &node;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = &node;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    ++size;
}
```

However, when I iterated through a four-element list, printing out each element as such:

```
LinkedList myList;
myList.insert_back(5);
myList.insert_back(6);
myList.insert_back(7);
myList.insert_back(8);

for(int i = 0; i < myList.length(); ++i)
{
    cout << myList.at(i) << endl;
}
```

the last element in the list printed first and then I would receive three garbage values such as in:

```
8
-403642776
-403642776
-403642776
```

I fixed this error by changing the way I create a new node in insert_back. This time, I used the new keyword.

```
void LinkedList::insert_back(int element)
{
    LinkedNode* node = new LinkedNode;
    node->data = element;
    node->next = 0;
    if(size == 0)
    {
        head = node;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = node;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    ++size;
}
```

This fixed the error, but I don't really understand why. For whatever reason, in my old code, head and tail were always pointing at the same address, but they are no longer when I use new. Why could this be?

Comment: I think we need a canonical "this is how you build a linked list in C or C++" answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba This question is not about how to build a Linked List, it's about a very specific error somehow relating to pointers and initialization of a struct that happened to cause an error in a Linked List.

Comment: @AnthonyRossello - and, if you were more experienced, you'd understand the point being made and wouldn't complain about it's lack of relevance. You'd also have used your debugger instead of this forum. Linked List implementors screw it up all the time and the mistakes are almost invariably the same. Just like the questions one sees on operator overloading of classes in c++ - it the same set of questions year after year after year. I suggest reading up on the STL and particularly, about the concept that containers 'own' their contents.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you for the recommendation and directing me to a concept I can read about. I will definitely check it out, but there is no need to take a personal shot at me when my initial comment certainly was not one.

Comment: @AnthonyRossello - you're welcome. Sorry if I bruised your feelings. It's a probably a good thing then, that I didn't decide to take a personal shot at you. ;) If you classify saying "if you were more experienced, you'd have done _this_ or avoided doing _that_" as a personal shot, you may well find much of the world an incredibly hostile place. Please note what I wrote is **very** different to saying "since you're such a novice and have no idea of what you're doing, learn how to use a debugger and pointers. I'm so sick of all these easily researched questions". - _that_ would be a shot at you.

Comment: <cont> I'm interested in building people up - helping them to succeed and to help others do the same. All the best & good luck. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the code `LinkedNode node = {element, 0}; ... head = &node;` of your first version stored the address of a local variable, which becomes invalid as soon as the `insert`-function finishes. This leads to undefined behaviour once you access this pointer later (e.g. when traversing your list).

In the second version, with `LinkedNode* node = new LinkedNode;`, you allocate memory dynamically, and such an object is valid until you explicitly delete it. Hence, the pointer remains valid and you may access it later on.